# How can I see parallel RC circuit effect on feedback line?

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, feedback

I want to observe the effect of the parallel RC circuit on the feedback line in the circuit shown below. The circuit is based on the [MCZ33810EK](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC33810.pdf) engine controller.

[image]

I expect this added structure to provide a decrease in the rise time, but I could not create it in the LTspice simulation, how should I proceed?

Since I don't know the structure of my feedback signal, I first tried it with a voltage source that increases over time and settles for a certain period of time, then I tried the relevant structure on the feedback pin of any IC, since the IC in the image does not have a SPICE model, but I still could not see the effect I expected. How can I observe it?

Comment: You may want to add your spice simulation to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Usually to observe something like this, I'd perform a closed-loop Bode plot.  To do this easily, you'll need to use a low-frequency VNA that can be used in a Bode plot application.  Since a Bode plot is just measuring response magnitude and phase relative to a stimulation in the feedback loop, you can construct a crude Bode plot setup from ordinary lab tools.

See this video: [Understanding Bode plots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ez1sZ2qtGJs)

Comment: Since this is not available on the integrated Ltspice, I tried to draw the feedback line (without transistor) and add this parallel RC circuit in series, but I could not get the desired result. I foresee an instantaneous voltage of around 400v coming from the coil to the feedback line, can't I simulate it this way? I tried with AC analysis and bodeplot, but I couldn't see the result I wanted, what I want to do is to observe the effect of the RC circuit by trying the situations with or without this parallel RC circuit in the feedback line.